# How to set data client-side in another dynamically loaded Bootstrap tab content

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Will I be able to continue as usual after  the jquery **load()** function?
Or is there something additional I need to do:

I have two **bootstrap tabs** with content. 
Tab1 has a data-grid (I chose bootgrid but anything goes), 
Tab2 has a label - to be set on client side (no server calls) according to selected row on grid (its single selection).
This is complicated further because Tab2's content (with the label) is created by a jQuery.load call.

Does the jQuery.load call make a difference?
Do I need to do anything special because of the load call?

Here's code (the load is remarked) built courtesy of the online  IDE atBootply.com: http://www.bootply.com/nXwOp1KCH9

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  // $("dvtab2content").load("tab2content.htm");
  // Notes: In the previous line load has been commented out. 
  // - The current code works ok. 
  // - The load() will bring a dvtab2content div with a 'dvtab2val1' div in it. 
  // My question is will the following lines still work after the load() function. 
  // if not, what needs to be done?
  $("#dvtab2val1").html($("#drptab1choice").val());
  $(document).on("change","#drptab1choice",function(e){
    $("#dvtab2val1").html(e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].text);
  }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- under construction -->
<div id="dvcontainer" class="container">
<div id="dvmainrow" class="row">
<div id="dvspacer" class="col-md-2"></div>
<div id="dvmaincol" class="col-md-10">
  
<div id="tabsmain" class="tabbable">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#dvtab1" data-toggle="tab">Section 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#dvtab2" data-toggle="tab">Section 2</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="dvtab1" class="tab-pane active">
      <div id="tab1content">
      <p>Section 1. </p>
<select id="drptab1choice" class="dropdown">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="susita">Susita</option>
  <option value="rom karmel">Rom Carmel</option>
</select>
        
      </div><!---tab1content ---->
    </div>
    <div id="dvtab2" class="tab-pane">
      <div id="dvtab2content">
        I'm in Section 2.
        <div id="dvtab2val1">this will be replaced</div>
      </div><!-- tab2content -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>  
  
</div>

</div>
```

Off topic - if you want to help further with this: 
A more complex and full version of this code, where I ask more non-generic questions is on ***correctMyCode*** here:
http://correctmycode.freeforums.net/thread/3/help-bootgrid-working

Comment: Working bootply of this: http://www.bootply.com/pashute/nXwOp1KCH9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/t4hk1dfj/

change

```
<div class=id="dvtabscontent" "tab-content">
```

to

```
<div id="dvtabscontent"  class="tab-content">
```

Comment: Thanks!!!  but that's an answer to my #fixMycode question, the code here runs perfectly, and my question is: What needs to be done (if at all) if I load the divMyContents dynamically.   I'll edit the question for clarity.

Comment: When the divMyContents changed, you don't need to do anything, Bootstrap Tabs should work fine as normal.